# Programmatically get Google search results

Tags: c++, google-search

How can I get Google search results from inside a program? I need to get an array of search results for a specified string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ requires a little more work then other languages. You will need to connect to Google's [REST Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje) and then use a JSON parser to parse out the search results. [Json.org](http://www.json.org/) has a collection of JSON parsers in various languages.

Answer (score 6):

Use their javascript search API http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/

They no longer support their [SOAP search api](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html) unfortunately

Comment: For non-javascript environments they do have a REST search api. http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje

Answer (score 2):

So... nine years later, you can no longer do that. You do get JSON, but it's quite short and just says "The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)"

Google Custom Search can search the entire web using the 'Thing' schema.org topic. https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513886?visit_id=636769478248533420-865620074&rd=1

Answer (score 1):

Google offers Ajax API for JavaScript programmers and a poor documentation for Python, PHP and Flash.By the way, If you are able to connect to remote http server with any other c++ library, you can do it. just change the url you are using and point it to: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q={My_CPP_Query}
You will get JSON data stream, that you will be able to work with.

Answer (score 1):

i remember i saw youtube tutorial on doing that, not sure about the library name but its something like _NT_SEARCH_GH:etcetcetcetcetcetc;