# is it possible to directly send search parameter to searrch engine from C program or shell script?

Tags: linux, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically get Google search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397313/programatically-get-google-search-results)

Is there any search engine to which we can send search parameters  programatically: that is to send search parameter from C program or shell script and I it possible to retrive first 2 pages using `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the major search engines offer an API. Google "web search api".

Answer (score 0):

This is a C language sample real life example to search *stackoverflow.com* with http://ask.com search engine :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(
        curl,
        CURLOPT_URL,
        "http://fr.ask.com/web?q=stackoverflow.com&qsrc=0&o=312&l=dir"
    );
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To run it, you should do that :

```
gcc <THE_CHOOSEN_C_SCRIPT_NAME> -lcurl && ./a.out
```

Moreover, you can play with `argv[]` array to type the search term as a parameter of the script

Comment: thankyou spurtnick . I will try and get back to you. could you let me know which is the "search parameter" like i want to send search parameter as "missing ;" to search where do i specify

Comment: Hello Members , could not run this above program as it gives error "could not find : curl " , but when i ran command `type curl` ,It gave me output  use/bin/curl.

Comment: deepak : the search parameters are in this URL : http://fr.ask.com/web?q=stackoverflow.com&qsrc=0&o=312&l=dir
Try to search your own words on http://fr.ask.com and keep the searched URL.
For the C script to run, you need the C cURL bindings, like libcurl4-nss-dev package on Debian/Ubuntu, see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/