# How to query Google programmatically?

Tags: search

I need a way to query Google programmatically and then read the "clean text" inside every URL. What is the best way to do it or if any tools already exists?

Programming language: preferably Java, Python or C#

Comment: Without a programming language or technology whatsoever it might be broad to answer this..

Comment: provide a language of your choice

Comment: Any programming language would be fine, I'm trying to explore the different options based on peoples' experiences.

Comment: @user3108337: take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397313/programatically-get-google-search-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Web Crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) to do this. Most programming languages have some sort of library that does this. For example if you use python, you can use [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).